# Declaring a variable within ForMember()

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to declare 2 variables, so I can convert this code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(
    destination => destination.destinationValue, source =>
        source.Condition(resolutionContext =>
            (resolutionContext.InstanceCache.First().Value as DestinationClass).destinationValue2 != null && (resolutionContext.InstanceCache.First().Value as DestinationClass).destinationValue2.Value != ((SourceClass)resolutionContext.Parent.sourceValue).sourceValue2  
            ||
            (resolutionContext.InstanceCache.First().Value as DestinationClass).destinationValue3 != null && (resolutionContext.InstanceCache.First().Value as DestinationClass).destinationValue3.Value != ((SourceClass)resolutionContext.Parent.sourceValue).sourceValue3                                                                          
        ));
```

into this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>().ForMember(
    var sourceObject = ((SourceClass)resolutionContext.Parent.sourceValue);
    var destinationObject = (resolutionContext.InstanceCache.First().Value as DestinationClass);

    destination => destination.destinationValue, source =>
        source.Condition(resolutionContext =>
            destinationObject.destinationValue2 != null && destinationObject.destinationValue2.Value != sourceObject.sourceValue2  
            ||
            destinationObject.destinationValue3 != null && destinationObject.destinationValue3.Value != sourceObject.sourceValue3                                                                          
        ));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: downvoter, at least have the guts to tell me what's wrong with my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's an anti-pattern, because mappers are supposed to be dumb, and thus you might want to resist the temptation of putting too much logic inside them. Querying the cache is the responsibility of your domain implementations.

Perhaps you should enrich the domain object you're mapping from rather than trying to add missing validation and information during the mapping process.

Comment: True. But I'm more interested in how to declare variables within the method call.